# Semantic UI Numeric Up Down control

Tags: spinner, semantic-ui, numericupdown

Is there any Semantic UI Numeric Up Down control with *minimum, maximum and step count* options ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not found such control so I made this code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="ui right labeled input">
    <input type="text" id="txtNum" value="5">
    <div class="ui mini vertical buttons">
        <button class="ui icon button" command="Up"> <i class="up chevron icon"></i>

        </button>
        <button class="ui icon button" command="Down"> <i class="down chevron icon"></i>

        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
// Constants
var KEY_UP = 38,
    KEY_DOWN = 40;

// Variables
var min = 0,
    max = 30,
    step = 1;

$('.ui.icon.button').click(function () {
    var command = $(this).attr('command');
    HandleUpDown(command);
});

$('#txtNum').keypress(function (e) {
    var code = e.keyCode;
    if (code != KEY_UP && code != KEY_DOWN) return;
    var command = code == KEY_UP ? 'Up' : code == KEY_DOWN ? 'Down' : '';
    HandleUpDown(command);
});

function HandleUpDown(command) {
    var val = $('#txtNum').val().trim();
    var num = val !== '' ? parseInt(val) : 0;

    switch (command) {
        case 'Up':
            if (num < max) num += step;
            break;
        case 'Down':
            if (num > min) num -= step;
            break;
    }

    $('#txtNum').val(num);
}
```

Here is the [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/3c32fdLt/).

Comment: IE tells more: 
    "If iframe document is assigned to 'document' variable and if iframe has been reloaded, IE will throw 'permission denied' error when accessing 'document' variable, see jQuery #13936". In your web site if should work

Answer (score 4):

We can use type as 'number' to get the required increment/decrement control.

```
<Input type="number"  />
```